# Some questions regarding the SPI configurations to interface with nrf24l01 radio transceiver

Tags: rf, stm32, embedded, wireless

I am looking at the product spec of [nordic nRF24L01](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf) transceiver module and trying to figure out how I can use with the STM32's SPI. The MCU that I have is STM32F4 nucleo and it's got 4 SPI peripherals with SPI1 and SPI4 running at 42MHz and SPI3 and SPI2 at 21MHz and the radio module itself supports the data rate of 250kbps, 1Mbps, and 2Mbps.

So considering this:

- any SPI peripheral would be more than enough to run this radio module since, for 42MHz, the data is sampled every 42MHz (23.9ns) whereas each data from the radio module comes in at 250kbps (each data every 4us)? Is this what you'd mainly consider while deciding about which peripheral to use? But then the enhanced shockburst packet is 32 bytes long. How do I picture this?
- any reason as to why the max SPI frequency is fclk/2? Does it have to do with full duplex transfer?

Comment: Determine the real thruput & frame latency you need with overhead and possible retransmits then choose the slowest RF data rate for best sensitivity and error rate.

Comment: There are many Nucleo boards with STM32F4, so which STM32F4 specifically it is?

Comment: STM32F401RE ....

Comment: Pick as low baudrate as you can, based on the radio baudrate. Maybe pick a SPI baudrate twice of the radio one or so. Because higher baudrates means more noise and more careful layout.

Comment: how could the MCU talk to the module when its baudrate is way higher? shouldn't it be <= radio's?

Answer (score 0):

The radio module SPI bus can only communicate at up to 10 MHz, so you anyway have to configure the STM32 SPI peripherals to 10MHz or below.

So which peripheral on STM32 you choose is irrelevant, as they all can be used at max speed.

Unfortunately, with your choice of 42 MHz system clock, and the SPI clock divisors that are available, the divisor of 4 exceeds 10 MHz, so you must select at least divisor of 8, which provides you with 5.25 MHz SPI clock.

PCB and wiring may also limit how fast you can communicate.

The max SPI frequency of the STM32 is FCLK/2 because how it is designed. Since it operates the state machine at FCLK, it can toggle the SPI clock at every FCLK, which gives max clock of FCLK/2.

Comment: So I don't really have to use a high frequency peripheral (SPI1) and instead can resort to SPI2 to run at 21MHz and maybe have a divisor of 4 to generate 5.25MHz SPI clock. and what state machine you're referring to?

Comment: You can use any SPI peripheral you want. All can provide 5.25 SPI clock. I am referring to the how the SPI peripheral is implemented and how uses the FCLK to generate SPI bit clock. It just can't generate clock that is at FCLK, it can generate clock that is FCLK/2, because that's how it is made to work.